# debug-mode python on windows

Tags: python, windows, pyqt4

For debugging an application I need to build the debug version of PyQt4 python modules on windows XP.
In the end files like PyQt4/QtCore_d.pyd are produced.
However these files can't be loaded directly in the installed release version of python:

- import PyQt4.QtCore does not work (no such module)
- import PyQt4.QtCore_d does not work (function initQtCore_d not defined)

I suspect the debug version of the PyQt4 modules can only be loaded by a debug version of python, which would interpret import PyQt4.QtCore as an instruction to load file QtCore_d.pyd file and run function initQtCore.

My questions are:

- Is the above assumption correct?
- Where can one find an official debug version of python (executable + libraries) for windows XP?
- If nowhere, how can one compile python on windows XP using open source software (like mingw, which I tried with no success yet)?

Comment: I compiled a debug version of python on linux with mingw and ran it on windows. The "import PyQt4.QtCore" problem remains the same.

Comment: The question is no longer relevant. For the problem at hand it is enough to compile a version of PyQt4 which links to debug Qt libraries and to release python library. While this cannot be done using options of the PyQt4 build configuration scripts, this is possible by hacking the generated Makefiles, replacing -lQtCore4 with -lQtCored4, etc.